# How can I custom checkbox in kendo-grid component?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

To custom the checkbox in **kendo-grid** component.

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-data *ngIf="col.checkbox" let-i="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox_{{i}}" [checked]="data.Discontinued" [disabled]="col.checkboxDisabled" class="thf-grid thf-grid-checkbox" />
            <label for="chkbox_{{i}}"></label>
 </ng-template>
```

The layout is showing with success, but the id's value is wrong, I'm writing the code like this "chkbox_".

Answer (score 0):

You can add a selector to your input, and then by using pseudoselector 
`::after` make it custom.
Or just using `[type="checkbox"]:checked/:not(:checked)` selectors make it custom.
Also, you shouldn't forget about specificity [read this to know more](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Here is a combination of two options I've metioned before:

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 1.25em; height: 1.25em;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
}
```

from [code pen example of custom checkboxes](https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp).

And if even specific selectors don't work you can always use `!important`

Comment: The layout is correct but it isn't working into the kendo-grid component.